# How to install 13.04 on alienware x51?

Tags: installation, 13.04

Dell released x51 with Ubuntu 13.04 preinstaled.
I was wondering if I can install it myself?
I have a 2012 x51 (i7 2600, nVidia 550) and after trying to install 13.04 i couldn't get it to boot up although the installatioon went fine.
Any ideas?
I tryed to install from USB drive following the tutorial for 12.04 installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. First thnx 2 both Mike and Sloan 4 assistance.
I managed to install Ubuntu 13.04 amd64 on my x51 alongside win7.
In the meantime i tried changing the boot mode to legacy, but it made no difference.
I tried both clean install and dual boot and Ubuntu couldn't bootup.
I also tried installing 12.04.2 but it got stuck every time during the installation while "updating hardware changes".
So after changing boot mode back and forth and rewriting iso to my usb drive several times using Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.3.1 i did the same thing as i did be4 and it worked this time.
I booted 13.04 "try ubuntu" with "nomodeset" command added by pressing "e" while in boot menu.
I used Gparted to create 2 ext3 partitions and 1 swap partition.
I continued installation by choosing "something else" when asked for inst type.
I assigned one of the partitions to be root(/) and other home(/home) and selected sd1 efi partition as a boot partition.
After the install was done i had to manually reset the PC cause it couldn't close all proceses.
On next boot it went directly to Ubuntu (boot mode is uefi).
I didnt't try any games yet but it seems the graphic drivers are working well for now.

I have to say I already did the same process several times earlier but it just didnt work.
I'll let u know how everything works after a few days of use.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I didn't have enough space in the edit field. To fix this first edit the boot flag with Gparted and make the disk bootable. Use this manual [Gparted flags](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-manage-partition-flags) Second recover grub using this software [Super grub disk](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/rescatux/)

Answer (score 0):

I was in same position as you...just got my X51 a few months ago. I had all kinds of issues trying to get it working and finally did. 
First thing you want to do is follow that Dell link that Mike C. posted to change your boot type to Legacy.

After that, reboot so you can launch the live CD in Legacy mode.
Install Ubuntu and tell the Installer to use entire disk. You don't want to specify the partitions yourself because the disk partitions are currently setup as GPT and they need to be MBR. If you specify your own partitions at this point, they will remain GPT.

Letting the installer use the entire disk automatically should convert it to MBR. If for any reason it fails to partition successfully as MBR, you can use a program called "gdisk" to convert it yourself.